# Filter a dataframe by passing "type" as input to columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
    id <- c(5738180,51845,167774,517814,1344920,517833,51844)
    measurement <- c("Length","Breadth","Breadth","Length","Length","Length","Breadth")
    map_flag <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
    cap_flag <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
    df.sample <- data.frame(id,measurement,map_flag,cap_flag)
```

**df.sample**

```
       id measurement map_flag cap_flag
  5738180      Length        0        1
    51845     Breadth        1        0
   167774     Breadth        1        0
   517814      Length        0        1
  1344920      Length        0        1
   517833      Length        0        0
    51844     Breadth        0        0
```

I am trying to create a function that takes a `df` and `type` as inputs and returns a `df` based on the filtered `type`

If I pass in

- `type = "map"`, it should filter the df using `map_flag = 1` column and return a df
- `type = "cap"`, it should filter the df using `cap_flag = 1` column and return a df
- `type = "Length"`, it should filter the df using `measurement = Length` column and return a df

**Desired outputs**

*type = "map"*

```
       id measurement map_flag cap_flag
    51845     Breadth        1        0
   167774     Breadth        1        0
```

*type = "cap"*

```
    id measurement map_flag cap_flag
  5738180      Length        0        1
   517814      Length        0        1
  1344920      Length        0        1
```

*type = "Length"*

```
       id measurement map_flag cap_flag
  5738180      Length        0        1
   517814      Length        0        1
  1344920      Length        0        1
   517833      Length        0        0
```

I am trying to do it this way but not getting what I wanted

```
 testFun <- function (df, type) {
      df <- df %>%
        {if (type==starts_with(map) filter(map_flag==1) }
      return(df)
    }
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. For `type == 'map'`, it selects the corresponding column (`map_flag`) and filters the rows which has value = 1. The same goes for `type == 'cap'` but `type = 'Length'` doesn't follow that logic. Are you sure it has to be included in the same function ?

Comment: @RonakShah I get your point but the logic that I am working with is set intentionally that way. 2 columns are flag and 1 is a non-flag.

Comment: So how do you want to implement the function ? How do you know which inputs are flag and which are non-flag. If there are only 3 inputs do you want to harcode the filters? Something like what @Park's answer does ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, Park's answer works well but I am trying to see if we could do it by not hard coding the filters. I would welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
func <- function(df, type = c("map", "cap", "Length")){
  if (type == "map"){
    df %>% filter(map_flag == 1)
  } else if (type == "cap") {
    df %>% filter(cap_flag == 1)
  } else if (type == "Length") {
    df %>% filter(measurement == "Length")
  } else {
    stop("select type amont map, cap, and Length")
  }
  
  
  
}

func(df.sample, "map")
      id measurement map_flag cap_flag
1  51845     Breadth        1        0
2 167774     Breadth        1        0
func(df.sample, "cap")
1 5738180      Length        0        1
2  517814      Length        0        1
3 1344920      Length        0        1
func(df.sample, "Length")
1 5738180      Length        0        1
2  517814      Length        0        1
3 1344920      Length        0        1
4  517833      Length        0        0
```

Error message is like

```
func(df.sample, "ma")
Error in func(df.sample, "ma") : select type amont map, cap, and Length
```

## New one

```
func <- function(df, type = c("map", "cap", "Length")){
  key <- paste0(type, "_flag")
  res1 <- try(df %>% filter(!!as.symbol(key) ==1), silent = TRUE)
  res2 <- df %>% filter(measurement == "Length")
  if(is(res1, "try-error")) res2 else res1

  
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is very close to what I want but is there a way we can do this by not hard-coding the filter values in the function?

Comment: @Sharath I'll make a try.

Comment: @Sharath I add a new code above.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 possible `type` inputs I would suggest to go with @Park's answer since it is easy to understand and does what is required.

I provide another option where you don't need to list down conditions for every input. It checks if `type_flag` column is present in the data and returns output based on that condition.

```
library(dplyr)

testFun <- function (df, type) {
  col <- paste0(type, '_flag')
  if(col %in% colnames(df)) {
    res <- df %>% filter(.data[[col]] == 1)
  } else {
    res <- df %>% filter(measurement == type)
  }
  return(res)
}

testFun(df.sample, "map")
#      id measurement map_flag cap_flag
#1  51845     Breadth        1        0
#2 167774     Breadth        1        0

testFun(df.sample, "cap")
#       id measurement map_flag cap_flag
#1 5738180      Length        0        1
#2  517814      Length        0        1
#3 1344920      Length        0        1

testFun(df.sample, "Length")
#       id measurement map_flag cap_flag
#1 5738180      Length        0        1
#2  517814      Length        0        1
#3 1344920      Length        0        1
#4  517833      Length        0        0
```

Comment: this is amazing. thanks a lot. I agree with you on Park's answer. It is simple to understand. I will use either of your answers based on my needs.

Answer (score 1):

This solution only needs base R and works with `data.frame` or `data.table` input:

```
testFun <- function(df, type) {
    
    key <- sprintf('%s_flag', type)

    if(key %in% names(df)) {
        return(df[df[[key]] == 1,])
    } else {
        # For other `type`s fall back to this - I think this is bad!
        return(df[df$measurement == 'Length',])    
    }

}
```

However, from a design point of view I would much prefer this:

```
testFun <- function(df, type) {
    if(type == 'map') {
        return(df[df$map_flag == 1,])
    }
    if(type == 'cap') {
        return(df[df$cap_flag == 1,])
    }
    if(type == 'Length') {
        return(df[df$measurement == 'Length',])
    }
    stop(sprintf('Invald type: %s', type))
}
```

or to require `type` to be a column in the input data.frame.